# target "CssG" does not exist in the project xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm using `visual studio 2017`, `xamarin v2.5.1`, I created a new `xamarin` forms project but I got this problem after build android project

```
The target "CssG" does not exist in the project.
```

[image]

what does this mean ?

after 3 days searching for the solution, I can't find it, any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally succeeded in solving this problem.

After building a NEW project using the Mobile App (Xamarin Forms) template, I first downgraded Xamarin.Forms to v2.5.0.280555 in all projects using Manage Nuget Packages on the references. Then I unloaded the Android project and opened the Android.csproj. In the Android.csproj I downgraded the Xamarin.Android.Support resources to 25.4.0.2, saved the document and Reloaded the Android project. After cleaning the solotion, closing it, deleting the (Android) obj and bin files and reopening the solution I could run it without errors.

Answer (score 5):

Closing Visual Studio and manually deleting the obj and bin folders worked for me! (my go-to move by the way)